# Animate UILabel with Autolayout turned on not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

**Below code is moving label's x position by 200pts its not animating**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:500.0f animations:^{
        self.myLabelContraint.constant=200 ;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myLabelContraint;
```

**above property connected to leading space to superView**

**Storyboard Pic**

[image: My Storyboard]

**Autolayout Constraints in inspector panel**

    [image: My Autolayout Constraints]

Comment: @bilobatum - leading space to: Superview - which is highlighted in pic above

Comment: Duh, it was in bold, but thanks. Why is your animation for 500 seconds?

Comment: @bilobatum - just punched in higher number to see animation is working  or not - lowering or highering a number does not have effect on final output as of now

Comment: Have you overridden any of the layout methods? viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews, updateConstraints?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; work if Needed layout ^_^
try add before it string setMethod like this;

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:500.0f animations:^{
        self.myLabelContraint.constant=200; //This string can be place somewhere
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: Your code is not animating the label it just moved the label that is what my question is about - test it before you post it

Comment: Can you share simple project example?

Comment: MB you need add litter `t` in your string: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myLabelContrain`

Comment: I tested my code. all work fine. Change animateWithDuration to 0.5f

Comment: I have editied my question for typo errors. In my project it is exactly same as above

Comment: i make simple project http://cl.ly/0s182h3d081m, you can try it, and verify with your code.

Comment: Everything is intact nothing is broken

Comment: do you watched my example? in my comment above.